# Angular.js detect external linking

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm currently making a small application with outlinking from my site. I would like to know where to place the detector. Right now I've placed it in my application root (`app.js`).

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']).config(function($routeProvider){
    'use strict';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: ''
        });
}).run(function($rootScope) {
    'use strict';

    $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
        return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
               && (obj.hostname != location.hostname)
               && (obj.href.match(/^http\:|https\:/));
    };

    $('a:external').on('click', function() {
        console.log("works");
    });
});
```

This is working perfectly but it feels wrong to place it in the `app.js` file. Any tips?

Edit: What I mean about outlinking is links thats not on my page. The hrefs are to another domain.

Comment: What do you mean by "with outlinking"?  Is it a typo and you meant "without linking"?

Comment: This will only bind click events once. When routing changes the view new links will not get bound. You should listen for `$routeChangeSuccess` broadcasts and bind click then.

Comment: @andand Check the edit, sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Ignore the router. I just want to create like what i've done with the jQuery but more like angular way.

Comment: @ViktorGardart the angular way is to create a directive that performs this activity, and then set it on the body.

Comment: What you're doing in run has nothing to do with starting the module.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Perfect, that was my thought. Thank you!